# TIBBO device server toolkit can't find the ip of my board with ESP32

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to use TIBBO Devices Server Tool to create a virtual COM port and connect a device via wifi to this port. Now my device has an ip address: 192.168.15.222 but it is not detected by TIBBO because it is "not in the local network." Actually giving the ipconfig command from prompt the device is not detected:

```
C:\Users\matti>ipconfig

Configurazione IP di Windows


Scheda Ethernet Ethernet:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione: fritz.box
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.108
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1

Scheda LAN wireless Wi-Fi:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda LAN wireless Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 1:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda LAN wireless Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)* 2:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Ethernet Connessione di rete Bluetooth:

   Stato supporto. . . . . . . . . . . . : Supporto disconnesso
   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:

Scheda Ethernet vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::4523:3660:ae7f:1a07%23
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.0.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :

Scheda Ethernet vEthernet (WSLCore):

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::6fce:fd5e:dc0:eed4%59
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.224.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :
```

then I gave the command arp -a and the device is found under interface 192.168.15.108 which (if I am not mistaken) is the address of the network board(?)

```
C:\Users\matti>arp -a

Interfaccia: 192.168.15.108 --- 0x15
  Indirizzo Internet    Indirizzo fisico      Tipo
  192.168.15.1          2c-91-ab-df-11-08     dinamico
  192.168.15.101        a0-d0-dc-e8-d1-10     dinamico
  192.168.15.109        a4-77-33-b5-11-5e     dinamico
  192.168.15.132        ec-be-5f-62-fd-2f     dinamico
  192.168.15.222        24-dc-c3-0e-78-d0     dinamico     //is this
  192.168.15.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statico
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statico
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statico
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statico
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico

Interfaccia: 172.21.0.1 --- 0x17
  Indirizzo Internet    Indirizzo fisico      Tipo
  172.21.15.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statico
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statico
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statico
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statico
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico

Interfaccia: 172.30.224.1 --- 0x3b
  Indirizzo Internet    Indirizzo fisico      Tipo
  172.30.234.81         00-15-5d-e2-0c-ed     dinamico
  172.30.239.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statico
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statico
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statico
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statico
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statico
```

[router screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sX8U.png)

I don't understand anything or little about networks,I hope you can help me.

even if TIBBO does not find the device you can still enter it manually by providing IP and SUBNET MASK.

I tried 192.168.15.222 and 198.168.15.1. CXome subnetmask I always entered 255.255.255.0 but none of these configurations worked

this is virtual serial COM:

https://ibb.co/f2d3tN5

https://ibb.co/jWYwhZW

https://ibb.co/p3PtSXR